# Show the problem: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {\int_0^n f(x) \,dx}{n}=A \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = A$

Tags: limits

I consider this problem.

Supposed a continuous map $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ and $A \in \mathbb R$

I want to prove that
 $$\lim_{n  \to \infty}\frac {\int_0^n  f(x) \, dx}{n}=A\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = A$$

Please tell me your idea.

Comment: No, it's not true.

Comment: The reverse implication is true, for $f(x)=\sin x$ is a counterexample for the current question

Comment: Thank you. There exists monotonically increasing sequence x_n which diverges infinity and satisfies f(x_n) converges to A as n → ∞?

Answer (score 0):

This is true if you reverse the direction of the arrow:
$$
\lim_{n\,\to\,\infty}\frac {\int_0^n  f(x) \, dx} n = A \quad\Longleftarrow\quad \lim_{x\,\to\,\infty} f(x) = A.
$$
An $\text{“ }\varepsilon\text{-}N\text{ ''}$ proof of that is not hard.

As remarked in comments, among functions that oscillate between two values, one can find counterexamples. In particular, for any periodic function that oscillates between two finite bounds, the average value of the function over one period will be the limit.

Comment: I change the conclusion.

Comment: There exists monotonically increasing sequence x_n which diverges infinity and satisfies f(x_n) converges to A as n → ∞?